# Got this error from Keras Tuner: Number of consecutive failures excceeded the limit of 3

Tags: deep-learning, keras, hyperparameter-tuning

I'm getting this error when I try to use Keras Tuner with my model:
*Number of consecutive failures excceeded the limit of 3. .... KeyError: 'mean_squared_error'*

Here's my code:

```
def model_builder(hp):
dnn_units_min, dnn_units_max = 16, 32
    
filters=2
filters_2=2
kernel_shape = (1,3)
kernel_shape_2 = (2,3)
input1 = Input(shape=(layers,len_seq,1,))
conv1 = Conv2D(filters, kernel_shape, activation='relu')(input1)
conv2 = Conv2D(filters_2, kernel_shape_2, activation='relu')(conv1)
flat = Flatten()(conv2)

input2 = Input(shape=(len_features,))
merge = concatenate([flat,input2])

dense1 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(merge)
dnn_units = hp.Int(f"0_units", min_value=dnn_units_min, max_value=dnn_units_max, step=1,)
dense2 = Dense(dnn_units)(dense1)
dense3 = Dense(16)(dense2)
output = Dense(3)(dense3)
model = Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs=output)
model.summary()
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
return model

objective = kt.Objective('mean_squared_error', direction='min')
tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder, objective=objective, executions_per_trial=10)

callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=10)
tuner.search([x_train,features_train], y_train,epochs=2000,verbose=0,batch_size=32, callbacks=[callback])
```

Do you know what could be the problem?
Besides that, I'm not sure about the objective parameter of the kt.Hyperband. I'm just using the same metric as in my loss parameter of my model.

Comment: Use Bayesian optimization instead of hyperband.

Comment: @AmirhosseinRezaei I just tried and I got the same error again